# How could we transfer large amounts of energy sourced in space to Earth?

Tags: low-earth-orbit

At the rate we are using energy, it is inevitable that we will need to source energy from outside of Earth, eg from space. I was wondering how one would transfer this energy from that energy collector (e.g. a solar array) to Earth to be used by us?

Comment: Where do you think our energy comes from now, exactly? There's only four sources of energy available to us: nuclear, solar, lunar, and geothermal. Most of the ones we use today (petrolchemical, wind, water, etc) are just convoluted forms of solar.

Comment: "The United Nations Development Programme in its 2000 World Energy Assessment found that the annual potential of solar energy was 1,575–49,837 exajoules (EJ). This is several times larger than the total world energy consumption, which was 559.8 EJ in 2012.[3][4]" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_energy

Comment: Can you clarify “at the rate we are using energy”? Is there a study showing power demand outracing supply?

Answer (score 10):

Various aspects of space-based solar power systems are described on 
[this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power)  To summarise briefly, the power is beamed down as electromagnetic radiation of some frequency to which the atmosphere is reasonably transparent. This is most likely to be optical or near IR or microwave. Microwave power can be converted efficiently at the Earth end, but the antennae needed are much bigger. Optical or IR solutions involve more loss, but can be done with smaller ground stations.

Comment: But there already is a space-based solar power system that is beaming down electromagnetic radiation of some frequencies to some of which the atmosphere is reasonably transparent.

Comment: @Ghanima But it is limited by the surface area of the Earth facing the sun, whereas e.g. a Dyson swarm is only limited by the amount of material available in the solar system/within reach of the civilization.

Comment: @Graipher, sure, but a civilization that burns 500 tons of fuel to get 10 tons of payload to LEO (which is not even remotely the place you'd want your Dyson swarm at) is probably not at the right point in their development to do such a thing.

Comment: @Ghanima Well that's one of the reasons we haven't built a Dyson swarm yet, but OP is talking about the future (that mystical land of almost infinite possibilities). In any case, you would probably start your Dyson swarm as a von-Neumann probe, so you only have to lift some initial population out of Earth's gravity field. Just be sure to put in a limit, or otherwise it will consume all matter in the solar system to produce more probes...

Comment: @Graipher "But it is limited by the surface area of the Earth facing the sun, whereas e.g. a Dyson swarm is only limited by the amount of material available in the solar system/within reach of the civilization." I doubt that. Beaming a large amount of energy to the Earth would pose massive logistical problems. And all of this would be extra energy that's being added to the Earth. While solar panels are simply intercepting energy that would have gone to the Earth anyway, a Dyson swarm is adding net energy.

Comment: A GEO power satellite with a microwave beaming system to the ground (eg MASER) could be more efficient than ground based PV panels as the GEO sat would always have no night, no atmosphere, and no weather.

Comment: Storing energy beamed to the earth will not be 100% efficient, and the efficiency losses will likely turn into heat.  Also, most processes produce waste heat when energy is used to do work.  So even adding a few percent to the amount of available solar energy by artificially beaming it to earth would probably warm up the earths atmosphere so much we couldn't live here.

Comment: @user4574 All energy ends up as heat eventually. All the energy sent from the satellite to the Earth, may as well be heat, as far as Earth's temperature is concerned. Unless it's being sent again from Earth to somewhere else (in which case only a percentage becomes heat on Earth, and the rest becomes heat somewhere else)